# Why react component does not render after state was changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Better to show you my code, it's compressed so not gonna take much time

```js
const PropertiesList: FC = (estatesObject) => {
    const [estates, setEstates] = useState(Object.values(estatesObject))

    const filterEstatesUp = () => {
        // just sorting an array of objects
        const filteredEstates = estates.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.price) - parseFloat(b.price))
        setEstates(filteredEstates)
    }
    const filterEstatesDown = () => {
        // just sorting an array of objects
        const filteredEstates = estates.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(b.price) - parseFloat(a.price))
        setEstates(filteredEstates) 
    }

    return (
        <> 
            <div onClick={() => filterEstatesUp()}>up</div>
            <div onClick={() => filterEstatesDown()}>down</div>
            {estates.map((estate, index) => {
                return(
                    <PropertyCard key={index} {...estate}/>
                )
            })}
        </>
    )
}
```

So problem is when i'm clicking on these divs `up` n `down` - nothing changes

**Update x:**
(I'm using next.js if that will help with something)I changed my code with yours recommendations but i got something else: now state is changing but browser still somehow does not show me another order of estates, so i see cards of estates staying in old order
This is my changed code:

```js
const PropertiesList: FC = (estatesObject) => {
    const [estates, setEstates] = useState(Object.values(estatesObject))

    const sortEstatesFromDown = () => {
        const sortedEstates = [...estates]
        sortedEstates.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.price) - parseFloat(b.price))
        console.log("FROM DOWN TO UP", sortedEstates)
        setEstates(sortedEstates)
    }

    const sortEstatesFromUp = () => {
        const sortedEstates = [...estates]
        sortedEstates.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(b.price) - parseFloat(a.price))
        console.log("FROM UP TO DOWN", sortedEstates)
        setEstates(sortedEstates)
    }

    return (
        <> 
            <div onClick={() => sortEstatesFromDown()}>up</div>
            <div onClick={() => sortEstatesFromUp()}>down</div>
            {estates.map((estate) => {
                return(
                    <PropertyCard key={estate.id} {...estate}/>
                )
            })}
        </>
    )
}
```

MAX price is 3.000.000 and MIN is 180.000, but as you can see after clicking both in turn - nothing changed again, there is usual order, that comes from server
[image]

**Update x+1:** This state is successfully changing(you can see it from console), but browser does not change order of cards, why?

Comment: `.sort` sorts the array in-place. You have to create a copy of the array first.

Comment: Please change `const sortedEstates = estates` to  `const sortedEstates = [...estates]`

Comment: @AseemGautam Changed. But still browser doesn't show me right order. But state is changing!)

Comment: @bluepuper Please update the original question so we can see the actual update.

Comment: Can you `console.log(index)` inside `estates.map((estate, index)` & see in what order is index being rendered.

Comment: @AseemGautam Jesus Christ, yes, that helped, i just mistyped something

Comment: @bluepuper glad you got it working, cheers :)

Comment: @AseemGautam thank you for attempting to investigate the problem, Aseem )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sort function does not create a new array, it mutates the old one. So you're rearranging the existing state, and then setting state with the same array. Since it's the same array, react thinks the state hasn't changed and skips rendering.

```
const sortedEstates = [...estates];
sortedEstates.sort(...);

setEstates(sortedEstates);
```

Comment: Thanks for recommendation and time spent! But please check the updates

Comment: @bluepuper Should be `[...estates]` here  `const sortedEstates = estates`.

Answer (score 1):

Now your code is just mutating your `estates` array and then passing the same array to the `setEstates` function so nothing changes because you pass the same reference of an array to that function and React thinks the state should not be changed so it doesn't re-render the component.

The solution looks like this:

```
const filterEstatesUp = () => {     
    setEstates((prevEstates) => {         
        const copiedEstates = [...prevEstates];         
        return copiedEstates.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.price) - parseFloat(b.price)); 
    }) 
}
```

In this case, I used the setState callback approach because I am changing the state that depends on the previous state, and I also recommend you to use it in order to avoid redundant bugs.

Then in the callback function, first I copy the previous array of `estates` which means that I am creating a completely new array with the same elements and after that, I sort and return the copied array.

According to the update, I will suggest you use `estate.id` as a key instead of index, in the place where you map all estates, I think the issue is hiding behind that:

```
return (
    <> 
        <div onClick={() => sortEstatesFromDown()}>up</div>
        <div onClick={() => sortEstatesFromUp()}>down</div>
        {estates.map((estate, index) => {
            return(
                <PropertyCard key={estate.id} {...estate}/>
            )
        })}
    </>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for time spent! I just tried it, but still nothing(

Comment: @bluepuper Make sure that you actually copy the array  [...prevEstates] because as I see in your update you haven't done it.

Comment: Finally fixed it! Thanks for recommendations, good to know in the future)